# How to unlock ubuntu Linux using python when screen is locked and hibernated

Tags: python, ubuntu, authentication, terminal

When my ubuntu locks out due to user locking the system, or due to inactivity, I'am not able to unlock and relogin using python.

The issue is that when my screen locks out, the screen goes black and blank (similar to hibernation but I'am using Desktop PC). The only way I have been able to bypass the hibernation is by pressing spacebar on my keyboard (as you would normally).

I tried to press space using pyautogui but its being ignored and the hibernation persists unless I press the physical keyboard.

I tried the following script which is successful in logging me back in as long as I first override the hibernation by pressing space bar.

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['loginctl unlock-session 2'],shell=True) #2 is my session id
```

Possible solution routes would be:

- To avoid hybernation altogether
- to bypass the hibernation using python script such that I can run the above code after to unlock/re-login.

Looking forward to your proposals. Much appreciated

Comment: This seems vaguely like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I would pursue the question of disabling hibernation if that's what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ultimately I'am trying to re-login, I'am just providing possible routes for solution but its up to the responder to propose. will clarify/edit OP .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dbus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/#whatisd-bus) to get gnome screensaver and disable it
Install dbus `pip install dbus-python`

```
import dbus
sessionBus = dbus.SessionBus()
screenSaver = sessionBus.get_object("org.gnome.ScreenSaver", "/org/gnome/ScreenSaver")
screenSaverIface = dbus.Interface(screenSaver, 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver')
screenSaverSetActive = screenSaverIface.get_dbus_method("SetActive")
screenSaverSetActive(False)
```

[source](https://github.com/floft/linux-control/blob/master/client/main.py#L472)